# Regex Match Url with non query param variable

Tags: regex, url

I see lots of answers for regex regarding query params but what about non-query params (url segment):

https:/my.com/verification/**c1fc67c94cc3871ef8cd6755a9278d0d**/email

The unique id in bold will vary in value and length

What regex can match for this url regardless of the unique id segment value or length?

Thanks

Comment: `^https:\/my\.com\/verification\/[0-9a-f]+\/email$` - assuming that I didn't miss anything that wasn't provided in your question.

Comment: Hey your URL is missing a `/` after `https:` right?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify the language it might not work in your case but you can use the following regex:

```
^https:\/\/my\.com\/verification\/[[:xdigit:]]+\/email$
```

[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/M3bm0x/1)

where `[[:xdigit:]]` is the character class for hexadecimal numbers as in POSIX (BRE), POSIX extended (ERE) and Perl/PCRE.

Note: there should be two slash `/` after the colon ":" to separate the protocol part and the domain part in your URL.

Check -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax